# Solving a system of non-linear equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following system of equations:

```
E1 = 1/4 (3 Subscript[a, 1][
       t] (4 Sqrt[
         2] + (-1 + 
           t) (-(-1 + t) ((1 + 2 t) Subscript[a, 1][t] + 
              t Subscript[a, 2][t]) - t^2 Subscript[a, 3][t]) + 
        t^2 (-3 + 2 t) Subscript[a, 4][t]) + 
     4 Derivative[1][Subscript[a, 1]][t]);
E2 = Subscript[a, 2][
     t] (3 Sqrt[2] + 
      1/8 (1 + 
         2 Sqrt[2]) ((-1 + 
            t) ((-1 + t) ((1 + 2 t) Subscript[a, 1][t] + 
               t Subscript[a, 2][t]) + t^2 Subscript[a, 3][t]) + (3 - 
            2 t) t^2 Subscript[a, 4][t])) + 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[a, 2]][t];
E3 = Subscript[a, 3][
     t] (3 Sqrt[2] - 
      1/8 (-1 + 
         2 Sqrt[2]) ((-1 + 
            t) ((-1 + t) ((1 + 2 t) Subscript[a, 1][t] + 
               t Subscript[a, 2][t]) + t^2 Subscript[a, 3][t]) + (3 - 
            2 t) t^2 Subscript[a, 4][t])) + 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[a, 3]][t];
E4 = 3/4 Subscript[a, 4][
     t] (4 Sqrt[
       2] + (-1 + 
         t) ((-1 + t) ((1 + 2 t) Subscript[a, 1][t] + 
            t Subscript[a, 2][t]) + t^2 Subscript[a, 3][t]) + (3 - 
         2 t) t^2 Subscript[a, 4][t]) + 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[a, 4]][t];
```

I tried

```
DSolve[{E1 == 0, E2 == 0, E3 == 0, E4 == 0}, {Subscript[a, 1], 
  Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[a, 4]}, t]
```

I also tried with `Solve` and `NSolve`, but the evaluation exhausted my patience. Any suggestion?

Comment: Nothing to do with this problem but in general I recommend avoiding the use of subscripts with symbols in computational code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide some initial conditions and use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n]

eqns = Join[{(1/4)*(3*a[1][t]*
                (4*Sqrt[2] + (-1 + t)*
                     ((1 - t)*((1 + 2*t)*
                               a[1][t] + t*a[2][t]) - 
                        t^2*a[3][t]) + 
                   t^2*(-3 + 2*t)*a[4][t]) + 
              4*Derivative[1][a[1]][t]), 
         a[2][t]*(3*Sqrt[2] + 
                (1/8)*(1 + 2*Sqrt[2])*
                  ((-1 + t)*((-1 + t)*
                            ((1 + 2*t)*a[1][t] + 
                               t*a[2][t]) + 
                          t^2*a[3][t]) + (3 - 2*t)*
                       t^2*a[4][t])) + 
           Derivative[1][a[2]][t], 
         a[3][t]*(3*Sqrt[2] - 
                (1/8)*(-1 + 2*Sqrt[2])*
                  ((-1 + t)*((-1 + t)*
                            ((1 + 2*t)*a[1][t] + 
                               t*a[2][t]) + 
                          t^2*a[3][t]) + (3 - 2*t)*
                       t^2*a[4][t])) + 
           Derivative[1][a[3]][t], 
         (3/4)*a[4][t]*(4*Sqrt[2] + 
                (-1 + t)*((-1 + t)*
                       ((1 + 2*t)*a[1][t] + 
                          t*a[2][t]) + 
                     t^2*a[3][t]) + (3 - 2*t)*
                  t^2*a[4][t]) + 
           Derivative[1][a[4]][t]} == 0 // Thread,
   Array[a[#][0] &, 4] == Range[4] // Thread];

soln = NDSolve[eqns, Array[a[#][t] &, 4], {t, 0, 1}][[1]];

Plot[
 Evaluate[Array[a[#][t] &, 4] /. soln],
 {t, 0, 1},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotLegends -> Array[a[#][t] &, 4],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you convert "Subscript[a, 2][t]" to "a[2][t]"? and are there any method that with your reply I have approximate "a1[t]" without figure?

Comment: @BahramAgheli - {E1, E2, E3, E4} /. Subscript[a,n_] :> a[n]     I do not know what you mean by "approximate 'a1[t]' without figure"

Comment: I want to use a1, a2, a3 and a4 for another system, but in your reply I I do not have function of a1, a2 and ....

Comment: @BahramAgheli - `a[1][t]` is an [indexed function] (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsWithHeadsThatAreNotSymbols.html)  of `t` defined on the interval `0 <= t <= 1` (domain constrained by `NDSolve`) similarly with `a[2][t]`, `a[3][t]`, and `a[4][t]`. They are used like any other function; e.g., they were plotted in my answer. The `Format` command causes them to be displayed in subscripted form in any output.

Comment: Dear Hanlon, Many thanks .